# JavaScript function not retrieving string from HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JavaScript and I am not understanding why my message is not being retrieved by a word count function. When I click the button with a message of multiple words, I am receiving '1' as the word count, which is incorrect. I have tested the calWords function which works correctly when using console.log(calWords(some message));. 
This code is written using requirements and I cannot use **.split()** or **regex**. Here is a link to the code: 
https://jsbin.com/rucicol/edit?html,js,console,output

```
<form class="userform">
  <label id="labeltxt">Enter a Message to Display Statistics</label><br>
  <textarea type="text" name="message" id='userInput'></textarea><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="showStats()">Submit</button>
</form>


// global variables
var numWords = 0;
var displayStats = document.getElementById('userInput').value;

// display stats
function showStats() {

   alert(calWords(displayStats));
}


// calculate words
function calWords(str) {

   for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
     if (str[i] === ' ') {
      numWords ++;
     }
   }
   return numWords + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because, when you create `displayStats` you take the value of the `textarea` at the moment of the creation (e.g. nothing).

To make your script working, you can "store" the reference to the `textarea` in `displayStats`and access his `value` when needed.

This is the corrected script:

```
// global variables
var numWords = 0;
var displayStats = document.getElementById('userInput');

// display stats
function showStats() 
   alert(calWords(displayStats.value));
}


// calculate words
function calWords(str) {
   for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
     if (str[i] === ' ') {
      numWords ++;
     }
   }
   return numWords + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Have been at this one all day.

Answer (score 2):

Add the code to get the text area content inside the function.

```
// global variables
var numWords = 0;


// display stats
function showStats() {
  var displayStats = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  alert(calWords(displayStats));
}


// calculate words
function calWords(str) {

  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === ' ') {
      numWords ++;
    }
  }
  return numWords + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason being you have initialised the `displayStats` globally which will be initialised once the page when load will happen. It would be better if you move `displayStats` inside click handler.

Also, if you are interested in knowing the number of words in the textarea, you should move your `numWords` inside the `calWords`, that way you will get the number of words which is present in the textarea.

```js
// display stats
function showStats() {
  var displayStats = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  alert(calWords(displayStats));
}

// calculate words
function calWords(str) {
  var numWords = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
     if (str[i] === ' ') {
        numWords ++;
     }
   }
   return numWords + 1;
}
```

```html
<form class="userform">
  <label id="labeltxt">Enter a Message to Display Statistics</label><br>
  <textarea type="text" name="message" id='userInput'></textarea><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="showStats()">Submit</button>
</form>
```